# pythonのmatplotlibを使用して,横棒グラフの塗りつぶしの柄を変えたい

Tags: python, matplotlib

pythonのmatplotlibを使用して,横棒グラフの塗りつぶしの柄を変えたいです．
現在，赤色と青色で判別できますが，モノクロにした際に判別できるようにしたいです．
具体的には破線や斜線，格子や水玉などの柄に変えて判別したいです．
何か方法はありませんか．よろしくお願いします。

data.txt

```
0   0    0.016   19.833
1   0   19.834   52.805
2   0   52.806   84.005
5   0   84.012  107.305
8   0  107.315  128.998
10  0  129.005  138.956
11  0  138.961  145.587
25  1   31.096   56.180
27  1   58.097   64.857
28  1   64.858   66.494
29  1   66.496   89.908
```

プログラムは以下のとおりです。

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: shift_jis -*-
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y, c, x1, x2 = np.loadtxt('data.txt', unpack=True)
color_mapper = np.vectorize(lambda x: {0: 'red', 1: 'blue'}.get(x))

plt.hlines(y, x1, x2, colors=color_mapper(c),lw=10)
plt.margins(0.1)

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

`hlines()` (`Line2D` オブジェクト) だと、あくまでも線を引くだけなので、`dashed` とか `dotted` といった程度しか [`linestyles`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html) に設定できません。

http://matthiaseisen.com/pp/patterns/p0203/ にあるように、各々の矩形を描画していく必要があるでしょう。

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

STYLES = [
  dict(fill=False, hatch='/', color='red'),
  dict(fill=True, hatch='\\', color='blue', alpha=0.5),
]
HEIGHT = 1

_, ax = plt.subplots()

with open('data.txt') as f:
  for line in f.readlines():
    y, c, x1, x2 = line.split()
    y = float(y) - HEIGHT / 2
    x1 = float(x1)
    width = float(x2) - x1
    c = int(c)
    ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((x1, y), width, HEIGHT, **(STYLES[c])))

plt.margins(0.1)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

numpy 使ったことないので、ファイル読み込み部分は素の Python コードです。必要に応じて適宜読み替えてください。

`STYLES` は `Rectangle()` へのキーワード引数をまとめたものです。

Comment: 解決できました。解答ありがとうございます。